# C++ freeRTOS Task, invalid use of non-static member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, task, freertos

Where is the Problem?

```
void MyClass::task(void *pvParameter){
     while(1){
         this->update();
     }
}

void MyClass::startTask(){
    xTaskCreate(this->task, "Task", 2048, NULL, 5, NULL);
}
```

But, I get this:

> error: invalid use of non-static member function

I cannot find any useful doc to check where is the mistake,
but i think that should be something like: (C++11's std::thread) e.g.:

```
xTaskCreate(&MyClass::task, "Task", 2048, (void*)this, 5, NULL);
```

solution that works for me:

```
void MyClass::task(){
    while(1){
        this->update();
    }
}

static void MyClass::startTaskImpl(void* _this){
    static_cast<MyClass*>(_this)->task();
}

void MyClass::startTask(){
    xTaskCreate(this->startTaskImpl, "Task", 2048, this, 5, NULL);
}
```

Comment: `this->task` is not valid if `task` is a non-static member function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use this pattern with a wrapper function for instanciating pthread with non-static member functions.
The function called in xTask is a static member function, calling the task function using void* pointer.
MyClass.hpp :

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass() {}
        ~MyClass() {}
    private:
        void update();
        void task();
        static void startTaskImpl(void*);
        void startTask();
 }
```

MyClass.cpp :

```
void MyClass::task(){
     while(1){
         this->update();
     }
}

void MyClass::startTaskImpl(void* _this){
    (MyClass*)_this->task();
}
void MyClass::startTask(){
    xTaskCreate(this->startTaskImpl, "Task", 2048, this, 5, NULL);
}
```

Comment: If you get `error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type` try changing `(MyClass*)_this->task();` to `((MyClass*)_this)->task();`

Answer (score 2):

According to this FreeRTOS official [thread](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/July_2010/freertos_Is_it_possible_create_freertos_task_in_c_3778071.html), you can write wrapper function to achieve this.