# C++ freeRTOS Task - "this" instance being passed as null

Tags: c++, class, arduino, esp32, freertos

In following the various attempts at getting a C++ class method to be passed to a freeRTOS Task, using `xTaskCreate` method, all my attempts don't end up passing actually class instance - thus `this` is empty.

The approved example shown at this link [C++ freeRTOS Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831114/c-freertos-task-invalid-use-of-non-static-member-function) doesn't work. Instead the `_this` is null, and then any referencing to member variables crashes.

```cpp
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass() {}
        ~MyClass() {}
    private:
        void update();
        void task();
        static void startTaskImpl(void*);
        void startTask();
 }
```

MyClass.cpp

```cpp
void MyClass::task(){
     while(1){
         this->update();
     }
}

void MyClass::startTaskImpl(void* _this){
    (MyClass*)_this->task();
    // _this is null (or 0)
}
void MyClass::startTask(){
    xTaskCreate(this->startTaskImpl, "Task", 2048, this, 5, NULL);
}
```

When it's run, the `_this` is null, but only in the `startTaskImpl` method.

It is hard to test examples since it needs the `freeRTOS` libraries, which I am using with `arduino` and `ESP-32` devices.

[freeRTOS](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/July_2010/freertos_Is_it_possible_create_freertos_task_in_c_3778071.html)  says this wrapping a static void method like `startTaskImpl` is the approved approach.

Comment: Are you sure `startTask` is called on a valid object?

Comment: Yes the object is valid in the `xCreateTask` but then in the `startTaskImpl` is't null. I believe the issue is with C++ Objects and the strange `void static` method that's needed as a wrapper to the instance method `MyClass::task`

Comment: Can you create a task in C and pass an argument to the task function?

Answer (score 2):

> (MyClass*)_this->task();

In C++, it should be

```cpp
static_cast<MyClass*>(_this)->task();
```

instead of `(MyClass*) _this->task();`

That is, cast the `void *` to `MyClass *` before calling its method.

**UPDATE**

Further to @KonaCurrents' comment *"I place a printf of _this in startTaskImpl and it's null"*, here is the test code to show that `_this` is not a `nullptr`.

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>

class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass() {}
        ~MyClass() {}
        // private:   all those methods should be public
        // void update();
        void task();
        static void startTaskImpl(void*);
        void startTask();
 };

 void MyClass::task(){
     while(1) {
         /* as update() is not provided by OP, replaced it with vTaskDelay() */
         // this->update(); 
         vTaskDelay(1);
     }
}

void MyClass::startTaskImpl(void* _this) {
    Serial.printf("%p\n", _this); // _this is CERTAINLY not a nullptr
    static_cast<MyClass*> (_this)->task();

}

void MyClass::startTask(){
    xTaskCreate(this->startTaskImpl, "Task", 2048, this, 5, NULL);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  MyClass obj;
  Serial.printf("\n%p\n", &obj);
  obj.startTask();
}

void loop() {
  
}
```

On my ESP32, this print out the value of:

```
0x3ffb226f
0x3ffb226f
```

Comment: To support your answer: According to [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), member access (`->`) and function call (`a()`) bind stronger than C-style cast (`(type)`). Hence, the member access is resolved first, than the result of the function call is converted to `(MyClass*)`. What I don't get: How this came through the compiler? With g++ it failed to compile: [demo on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4836dd31073951b)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I think OP never mentioned that the code actually can't go through the compiler, it would get an "error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type" on ESP32.

Comment: The above code was from the original posting. I've played with it as well, including the update you suggest (and was a comment in OP).  I place a printf of **_this** in **startTaskImpl** and it's **null**. So this post is questing how to get the object sent. It's valid at the **xTaskCreate** location.

Comment: It should be `static_cast<MyClass*>(_this)->task()` rather.

Comment: @KonaCurrents, *"I place a printf of _this in startTaskImpl and it's null".* Maybe you should post your exact code to show what and how exactly you use the printf(). It certainly not null, see **UPDATE** in my answer for the complete test code.

Comment: I'll try your version. Maybe I call startTask wrong. Thanks.

Comment: After testing, the `4th` argument to `xTaskCreate` needs to be the instance `this`. Using NULL only seems to work with a static method shown in links below (eg. `keyUnitLED`) 

The 4th argument is `pvParameters` (and is used in the examples above) defined in [free RTOS manual](https://www.freertos.org/a00125.html).

The original Arduino code had static methods and that 4th parameter was NULL. So my own code used NULL (even though the code example I posted had it right).  [KeyUnit example](https://github.com/m5stack/M5Stack/blob/master/examples/Unit/KEY/KEY-DEMO2/KEY-DEMO2.ino).